# Can't find XPath value on an AngularJS input field

Tags: angularjs, selenium

Is there a way to get the actual value of the input field for Selenium test?

For example:

I need to check if the field has a value and if the value is correct:

On the page:

**Manager's Email:** *branch_manager@example.com*.

I need to get the value *'branch_manager@example.com'* but when I use XPath only the below is showing.

```
<input type="text" 
       name="Email" 
       id="Email" 
       ng-model="vm.email" 
       placeholder="" 
       maxlength="200" 
       ng-readonly="vm.editField" 
       ng-required="!vm.viewState" 
       ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&amp;�*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/" 
       class="ng-pristine ng-valid md-input ng-valid-pattern ng-valid-maxlength ng-valid-required ng-touched" 
       readonly="readonly" 
       aria-required="false" aria-invalid="false">
```

I'm only getting the `ng-model` which contains the value what I actually want is the value inside the model. Is it possible?

Comment: `value inside the model` I don't see any attribute as `model` other then `ng-model`

Comment: i have updated the question. Thanks for looking into this!

Comment: It is not a right HTML you providing, since there is nowhere `branch_manager@example.com`

Comment: You can't access what's inside "vm.email" through this HTML

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the input text field value using the `getAttribute()` method as below

```
    WebElement emailId=driver.findElement(By.id("Email"));
                        ( or )
    WebElement emailId=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='Email']"));

    //It will give the Value which is present in the input text field
    System.out.println(emailId.getAttribute("value"));
```

Comment: @BoogerT: Please check the answer and accept by clicking on the tick button and also give the up vote by clicking on the up arrow button